# Is it possible to plot a "checkerboard" type plot in python?

Tags: python, plot

I have a data set that has two independent variables and 1 dependent variable. I thought the best way to represent the dataset is by a checkerboard-type plot wherein the color of the cells represent a range of values, like this:

[image]

I can't seem to find a code to do this automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a plotting package to do this.  For example, with matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

X = 100*np.random.rand(6,6)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
i = ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')
fig.colorbar(i)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this years later as myself, what Original Poster wants is a heatmap.

Matplotlib has documentation regarding the following example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-annotated-heatmap-py).
[image: 2D map with values, title and axes annotations]